# Count Hexagons inside a Rectangle?

Tags: java, computational-geometry

I'm looking for an algorithm to count hexagons that fall within a rectangular area, whether cropped or not.

I know the following:

```
rectWidth = 1280;
rectHeight = 720;
hexRadius = 50; // middle to corner
hexHeight = hexRadius * 2;
hexShortSpan = hexRadius * 0.5;
hexLongSpan = cos(radians(30)) * hexRadius;
hexWidth = hexLongSpan * 2;
hexSide = hexRadius + hexShortSpan; // this is not a side but side + shortSpan for horizontal rows
```

Can't figure out the mod op to get the right result.

```
float A = rectWidth / hexWidth;
float B = rectHeight / hexSide;
float hexCount = A * B +????;
// etc. etc. not sure about the rest...
```

Rob

Here's an image…

http://moggach.com/media/img/hexGrid.jpg

Comment: What do you know about hexagon positioning? Do you have 'anchor' hexagon? What is orientation? Like I draw it or, rotated?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'anchor' orientation is 'pointy' ie. rotated

Comment: With anchor I mean defined position of one hexagon in rectangle. It can be input parameter or you can have some request on it. In picture, lower left corner of rectangle is also "lower left" corner of hexagon. Is it true for all your configurations?

Comment: top left corner is middle of first hexagon and hex coord (0,0)

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the area of a hexagon, and divide the area of the rectangle with the area of the hexagon.

The area of the hexagon is

a*a * (3 * sqrt(3)) / 2

where a is the length of a side of the hexagon.

Comment: Although this doesn't account for areas chopped up to cropped hexagons - if 3 cropped hexagon add up to the area of a hexagon, it's counted as one...

Comment: yeah this is only whole hexagon areas and has no knowledge of cropped hexagons on either sides of the rectangle

Comment: who gave this a rating? it's not a solution.

Comment: That would be an optimistic upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

<s>**Hint:** count numbers of hex corners on one side. E.g. count all hex right corners (X's): ...</s>

With top left corner in the middle of first hexagon, situation is less general. It can be solved with counting:

- how many hexes are in first row (split by upper border)
- how many hexes are in second row (just below first one)
- how many rows are of first row type (every second from first row)
- how many rows are of second row type (every second from second row)

This is python version of code:

```
from math import ceil, cos, sqrt
rectWidth = 1280
rectHeight = 720
hexRadius = 50
hexHeight = hexRadius * 2
hexHalfHeight = hexRadius/2
hexWidth = hexRadius * sqrt(3)

# First one is corner, ceil() calculates others in row
num_in_first_row = 1 + ceil( ( rectWidth - hexWidth ) /hexWidth )
num_in_second_row = ceil( rectWidth / hexWidth )

# First one is corner, ceil() starts from upper point of next hex on left border
num_of_first_rows = 1 + ceil( ( rectHeight - 2 * hexRadius ) / ( hexHeight + hexRadius ) )
# Starts from upper point of first hex in second row. Coords (hexWidth/2., hexHalfHeight)
num_of_second_rows = ceil( ( rectHeight - hexHalfHeight ) / ( hexHeight + hexRadius ) )

num = num_in_first_row * num_of_first_rows + num_in_second_row * num_of_second_rows
print num
```

Comment: looking for a programmatic solution - going through and finding which top corner in each hexagon is within the rectangle is not impossible but not very efficient

Comment: You only have to find first one (which is probably input parameter), since neighbouring columns are in 3/2 edge length distance, and vertically on sqrt(3)/4 edge length. Values you already have.

Comment: should also mention that i'm dealing with pointy hexagon grid layout. (rotated 90 deg)